# StringBuilder renders html tags

Tags: asp.net, stringbuilder

Why does the stringbuilder render the HTML tags in the webpage?

It ends up looking like this in on the webpage

```
<b>UserAccountID:</b> 25xxx </br><b>vcAccessNumber:</b> 08505xxxx</br><b>DnisNumber:</b> 08505xxxx</br><b>Description:</b> Samtalsfxxxxx</br>
```

here is the code

```
 stringBuilder.Append("<div><b>Table name: "+table.TableName +".</b></br> Contains "+table.Columns.Count+" columns and "+ table.Rows.Count+" rows</br>");
    stringBuilder.Append("Column names and first row data: </br>");


    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("<b>" + table.Columns[i].ColumnName + ":</b> " + table.Rows[0][i] + "</br>");     
    }

    stringBuilder.Append("</div>");
```

Comment: The line break tag in XHTML is written as `<br/>`, not `</br>`.

Comment: StringBuilder doesn't do this, how do you print the string on the web page?

Comment: I don't think it's the StringBuilder. How do you output the resulting string on the page? That's likely where the HTML is encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `StringBuilder` - it is about how you are writing the string out to the page.

In your case, it looks like the string is getting HTML encoded. You need to ensure it is written literally, without any encoding.